# How to Update a Configurable Attribute by Javascript

Tags: javascript, configurable-product

On [this website](http://nickwan.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/magento-how-to-update-configuable-attribute-by-javascript/) there is a very clear explanation how I could trigger the configurable product dropdowns when I use jQuery.

But when I do this:

```
..
var element=$('attribute140');
spConfig.configureElement(element);
..
```

I get this JS error: `TypeError: spConfig is undefined`.

**UPDATE:**
This is the noconflict code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    var magentoAttrColor = 140;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ...
```

And when I do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        alert('go');
    });
</script>
```

The alert box doesn't pop up.

Answer (score 2):

Check your page source, it should be defined in

```
view/type/options/configurable.phtml
```

As

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

Eg. Look at the source of [this product](http://me-s1.sonassihosting.com/apparel/shirts/coalesce-functioning-on-impatience-t-shirt.html)

---

So either you are missing that definition from your `phtml` file - or you are trying to execute your JS before the document is '[ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)' - *Ie. the DOM isn't fully loaded*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After var spConfig I have "jQuery(document).ready(function()" so that would be the ready... (right?) but still the same error.

Comment: Well assuming that your code is within the document ready and that you have set up jQuery in `noConflict` mode - it should *just work*.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. But I'm pretty sure it has to de with the jQuery.noConflict(); please see my update, it's being appreciated :-)

Comment: The fix is below...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try and insert the `jQuery.noConflict();` right after including jQuery in the head?
I've never seen it being placing in the body tag.

Optionally try a jQuery version from the 1.x family, I've used it in a lot of setups and it never caused any issues. Might be 2.x related?

Comment: Yes I did, somehow I couldn't find it after all :-(

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed it by editing `configurable.js`

on line 184:

```
//if(prevConfig.config.allowedProducts
//&& prevConfig.config.allowedProducts.indexOf(options[i].products[j])>-1){
         allowedProducts.push(options[i].products[j]);
//}
```

I've found more people having this issue, not sure if browser related... but this works.

Comment: That seems like a bad idea — those checks are there fore a reason.